# /etc/network/interfaces static routes script

Tags: networking, scripts

Is there any "scriptable" way to add static routes to the interfaces file in Ubuntu/Debian?, I don't want to use custom scripts, just the official way to add a "up route add -net...." to the correct interface.

I hope you guys can give some advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your script fragment to the `/etc/network/if-up.d/` directory. Look at `/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd` (and the others) for How-To-Do-It.

Comment: Well thats a good answer, but I was looking for something, some tool to manipulate the interfaces file, you know, to add something, or to remove something, for instance, you may want to add a netmask, or a dns search, or to remove a static route.